# help with NullReference exception in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

The following is a web method that is called from ajax, I have verified with firebug that the script is indeed passing two string values to my method:

```
public string DealerLogin_Click(string name, string pass)
{
    string g="adf";
    if (name == "w" && pass == "w")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["public"] = "pub";
        g= "window.location = '/secure/Default.aspx'";
    }

    return g;
}
```

I'm passing "w" just for testing purposes. If I delete the if block then I don't get an error back from the server. I'm confused.

Comment: can you post the stack trace of the exception please - at present `.Current` or `.Session` are the only candidates

Comment: Can you verify if ASP.Net has assigned its session id at the time this web method is called?

Comment: The problem was either .Current or .Session. There was not previous sessions so I wrote the syntax wrong to create one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing the stack trace, I would guess that `HttpContext.Current` or `HttpContext.Current.Session` is `null`.

Comment: @SLaks (and Andras): Doh! I've been in CMMI training all day, my brain is fried. Thanks.

Comment: @Jeff - s'okay, you're among friends

Comment: @Jeff Yates, You are correct. I don't know why I wrote that the way I did. Should be Session["public"]="pub";

Comment: @nick: Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff is correct, but I wanted to add that using session within a web service requires that session be turned "on":

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public string DealerLogin_Click(string name, string pass)
{
    string g="";
    if (name == "w" && pass == "w")
    {
        Session["Public"]="pub";

        g= "window.location = '/secure/Default.aspx'";
    }

    return g;
}
```